What is the easiest way to turn 1 kV DC to 10 kV DC?
What is the simplest method for me to take quick 1 kV DC pulses, and turn them into 10 kV DC pulses or higher?
What might my circuit look like?
Edit to provide more detail: Water rolling down a short hydrophobic slope will induce a voltage of up to 1200 volts into each water droplet, and a small amount of micro amps.
We don’t care about the current really, but we want to take these quick 1000 volt discharges and up them to 10,000 if possible? It would be a monumental improvement for the project I’m working on.
My idea was to take capacitors and diodes in stages like a regular boost circuit, would this work?

DC pulse is an unexpected concept. What is the duration of a single pulse? Does the output need to be isolated? Unidirectional pulses starting from 0? Try simulating a transformer there, starting with 1:10…

The easiest way? Probably something involving a Keysight B1505 and its ultra-high-voltage module. I wouldn't want to touch anything that high voltage myself, would much rather buy equipment that more experienced engineers designed already.

Probably a flyback transformer, depending on how your 1 kV pulse looks like.

Hi guys, my apologies for not providing more detail in the original question, I have added more.

1kV pulses at what current?

The simplest method would typically be a transformer. A pulse of DC is put across the primary and you jack the voltage up on the secondary. We've been doing that since the first carrier pigeon was trained. Of course, the current transfer will be reduced substantially but you never mentioned a current requirement. Other schemes would include charging 10 capacitors up to 1000V and then stack them in series. A Marx Generator is a fun option. It's basically a ladder of capacitors diodes/resistors, and spark gaps. If you had AC to start with, you have other options. For example, you could make a voltage multiplier array up to arbitrarily high voltages.

I have decided to go the capacitor and diode route, and will add stages until the output is 10kv or close to. I am dealing with very low current (micro amps on the input), all I care about is amplifying the voltage itself on the output. So if I create these capacitor and diode stages, will this work as planned? Does the very low current affect this operation? (Gets to a point where the current is too low to operate the capacitors/diodes?)

@user3838548 What is your input source?

I was reading how water rolling down a hydrophobic surface a short bit actually can cause the droplet to develop close to 1000 volts until it discharges. I wanted to see if I could take each of those ~1000 volt quick pulses and see if they could be stepped up 10x? Current isn’t a concern if it gets lower each stage, just want to adjust the voltage. (As long as it still operates the capacitors etc)

@user3838548 First of all, that is context that would have been super useful in the original post - no one is going to assume that's what you were planning on doing. Second, why would you want to do this? There are much better ways to generate high-voltage that doesn't involve "harvesting water across hygroscopic surfaces". This sounds like a static electrical phenomenon and my suggestions aren't well suited for your application.

Apologies for that sir, yes it would be for a static electric phenomenon. I know there are better ways, but for the project I’m working on this could potentially be a huge improvement if it’s possible to step it up like that. The droplets can develop 1000 volts and a low amount of micro amps, and my output requirement is 10kv and a negligible amount of current in picoamps.
Do you think it would be possible to step up each pulse via the diodes and capacitors in stages?

@user3838548 No I don't think what I suggested would work very well. I would approach your problem by trying to get 10 "rolling" drops of water to end up in series after they develop their respective charges. Post a reference, picture, or diagram depicting how one drop creates this high voltage. This might get better results on a chemistry or physics page; this is not traditional "electronics design". Still interesting though.

I don't think the transformer method will work well because of capacitive losses.

Separate the drops by a larger distance before discharging them.
maybe using some sort of hydrophobic ramp
The drops carry charge, so the further you separate them the more room the is to generate potential
